# PyQt4 on Python3.x segmentation fault

Tags: python, linux

I got segmentation fault in python 3.5.2 on importing `PyQt4` :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *     
from PyQt4.QtCore import *    
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
```